# Quarto/pandoc: merge with instead of rewriting the intermediate Markdown file

Tags: markdown, pandoc, quarto

Quarto (or better, pandoc in the background) creates an intermediate Markdown file before preparing the final output.

Sometimes though a user would want to edit this file to add changes that would not need to run any code, like text changes, or adding comments. But the next round of rendering will remove these changes since it overwrites the file.

Is it possible to merge the rendered file with the existing Markdown, as git does for example? Maybe using some pandoc or YAML option?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But I guess you could translate the edited file back into Markdown, and then merge the two Markdown files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most things, this would certainly be *possible*, but also prohibitively *hard* to set up.

A much better way is probably to rely on Quarto's [caching feature](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/caching.html). This should prevent any unnecessary repetitions when running computations.

```yaml
---
title: "My Document"
format: html
execute: 
  cache: true
---
```

See the link above for more info and alternatives, e.g., “freezing” the document by setting `freeze: true`.

Comment: thanks, yeah I'm aware of the feature. The backside story is that I'm trying to "sell" the markup workflow to non-R people for report development. So I'm investigating all implementations that minimize barriers.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this AFAIK; it would have to be built manually. I forgot to mention: the `qmd` to `md` conversion is not done by pandoc but performed by either knitr or quarto.